error when training yolov7 model in google colab
This is the code:
%cd /content/gdrive/MyDrive/yolov7
!python train.py --batch 16 --cfg cfg/training/yolov7.yaml --epochs 55 --data {dataset.location}/data.yaml --weights 'yolov7.pt' --device 0

This is the error after some output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/yolov7/train.py", line 613, in <module>
    train(hyp, opt, device, tb_writer)
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/yolov7/train.py", line 336, in train
    for i, (imgs, targets, paths, _) in pbar:  # batch -------------------------------------------------------------
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1181, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/yolov7/utils/datasets.py", line 110, in __iter__
    yield next(self.iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 631, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1346, in _next_data
    return self._process_data(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1372, in _process_data
    data.reraise()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 705, in reraise
    raise exception
cv2.error: Caught error in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 308, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)  # type: ignore[possibly-undefined]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 51, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 51, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/yolov7/utils/datasets.py", line 542, in __getitem__
    img, labels = load_mosaic(self, index)
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/yolov7/utils/datasets.py", line 756, in load_mosaic
    img4, labels4, segments4 = random_perspective(img4, labels4, segments4,
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/yolov7/utils/datasets.py", line 1059, in random_perspective
    img = cv2.warpAffine(img, M[:2], dsize=(width, height), borderValue=(114, 114, 114))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:1806: error: (-215:Assertion failed) ifunc != 0 in function 'remap'

The reason for the error and where can I solve this. In while files, I can solve this and how to solve.
